# Initialize __m256i from 64 high or low bits of four __m128i variables

Tags: c++, sse, simd, avx, avx2

Suppose I have four `__m128i` variables that contain data resulting from some computation. For example, let us say:

```
__m128i a = _mm_set_epi64x(1, 11);
__m128i b = _mm_set_epi64x(2, 22);
__m128i c = _mm_set_epi64x(3, 33);
__m128i d = _mm_set_epi64x(4, 44);
```

I want to initialize two `__m256i` variables, where the first one contains all the high 64-bits of four variables, and the second one contains the low 64-bits of each. So I want to have:

```
__m256i x = ...; // x = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
__m256i y = ...; // y = { 44, 33, 22, 11 };
```

The obvious way of doing this is to use `_mm256_set_epi64x` and `_mm_extract_epi64`. However, it's probably not particularly fast. Is there a faster way of doing it? In particular, for accessing the 64 high bits, I see no suitable load (there is a load for the lower 64 bits in SSE2) or shuffle instruction (there seems to be no "64-bit shuffle").

Comment: What's the instruction you saw to load the lower 64 bits?

Comment: @JohnZwinck [_mm_loadl_epi64](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/index.htm#GUID-5922A85B-1237-423F-866C-82560B230BBB.htm), but it's for the 128-bit registers.

Comment: You mention there is no 64-bit shuffle, but who would need one?  We have _mm256_shuffle_epi32 and if we want to shuffle 64-bit chunks we can just claim we're doing 32-bit chunks and do the shuffle such that adjacent 32-bit chunks move together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, this is a simple 4x2 transpose (or 2x4 tranpose?).

Here's a code that is working for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    __m128i a = _mm_set_epi64x(1, 11);
    __m128i b = _mm_set_epi64x(2, 22);
    __m128i c = _mm_set_epi64x(3, 33);
    __m128i d = _mm_set_epi64x(4, 44);

    __m256i ac = _mm256_castsi128_si256(a);
    ac = _mm256_inserti128_si256(ac, c, 1); // {3, 33, 1, 11}

    __m256i bd = _mm256_castsi128_si256(b);
    bd = _mm256_inserti128_si256(bd, d, 1); // {4, 44, 2, 22}

    __m256i high = _mm256_unpackhi_epi64(ac, bd);
    __m256i low = _mm256_unpacklo_epi64(ac, bd);

    uint64_t t[4];

    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) t, high);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        cout << t[i] << endl;
    }

    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) t, low);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        cout << t[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This should compile into 4 instructions.

Comment: Clever.  My attempt was looking like six instructions.